# Shortcut symbols are not properly showing up in menu of LyX

Tags: macos, applications, font, icon

This is a screenshot I took while using LyX, which a WYSIWYG Latex editor.

[image: LyX screenshot]

As you can see some symbols for shortcut keys are broken and what I see is a bunch of question marks. How can I fix this?

- macOS: High Sierra 10.13.6
- LyX Version: 2.3.2 (8 December 2018)
- Library directory: `/Applications/LyX.app/Contents/Resources/`
- User directory: `~/Library/Application Support/LyX-2.3/`
- Qt Version (run-time): 5.9.7
- Qt Version (compile-time): 5.9.7